# Magento Migration Error On Main Server

Tags: magento

I am trying to migrate the website from test.hub.com.pk to hub.com.pk

the website is working on test.hub.com.pk but when migrating hub.com.pk with the same database credential on the same webserver it is not working it is giving error

I have also run some commands to give permission

```
like chmod -R o+w var media app/etc

and find . -type f -exec chmod 644{} \;
    find . -type d -exec chmod 755{} \;
    chmod 550 mage
```

Comment: Can you please tell me which kind of error you are facing?